# AutoFocus does not seem to fire when the page loads through stack navigation. It ends up focusing the textInput but does not open the keyboard

Tags: react-native, keyboard, autofocus

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.password}
    returnKeyType="go"
    secureTextEntry={true}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    autoFocus={true}
    fontSize={16 / PixelRatio.getFontScale()}
    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
    onSubmitEditing={this.validate}
/>
```

Though the autoFocus is true, the keyboard is not showing but the Text input field is focused. How can I popup the keyboard when the interface is loading..